# How to compute rotation about a random unit vector

Tags: linear-algebra, classical-mechanics

Consider a "new" coordinate system $O \bar{x_{1}}\bar{x_{2}}\bar{x_{3}}$ that is obtained by a  counter clockwise rotation of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians about an axis that coincides with the unit vector $$\underline{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\underline{e_{1}} + \underline{e_{2}} )$$

in the "old" coordinate system $Ox_{1}x_{2}x_{3}$ as indicated in the sketch below
[image]

if $\beta_{ij} = cos(\bar{x_{i}},x_{j})$ (angle between the 2 vectors) calculate $\beta_{ij}$

what I had attempted what I tried creating a new basis and rotating that(so first basis white, second red,third blue) the comparing the blue axis to the white. but I keep getting zero when I do my calculations

[image]

could someone assist, please

Comment: for a general answer see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle

Answer (score 0):

Let’s denote by $R=(e_1’,e_2’,e_3’)$ the image of $e_1,e_2,e_3)$. One has

$$R=\begin{bmatrix}
{1\over 2} &  {1\over 2} & {1\over\sqrt{2}}\\
{1\over 2} &  {1\over 2} & -{1\over\sqrt{2}}\\
- {1\over\sqrt{2}} & {1\over\sqrt{2}} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Sorry could you please explain how you got to this